# What that %%~ do in a Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file

In a Windows batch file that I inherited and have to edit, there's this line (and I'm simplifying for readability):

```
FOR %%m in (*.XML) DO IF EXIST D:\DATA\%%~m COPY D:\DATA\%%~m subdir
```

Which copies XML files in `D:\Data` to the `subdir` subdirectory of the current folder.

My question is what does `%%~m` to that `%%m` wouldn't do?

Comment: it removes any surrounding quotes. See `for /?`

Comment: What if the file names have blank spaces?

Comment: Then use `if exist "D:\Data\%%~m" copy "D:\Data\%%~m" subdir`.  That should work regardless of whether the path or filename contains spaces.

Comment: That *particular* usage of `%%~` strips quotes, but in general it depends on the succeeding characters. `%%~nm` would return the `name` part of `%%m` for instance; `%%~tm` the datstamp of the file, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been answered in the comments from @Stephan, @rojo, @Magoo.

Summarised here so the question is marked as answered:

The `~` character in `%%~m` removes the surrounding quotes from the variable `m`.

If it is a file name that contains spaces you can put the quotes back around the whole path name, for example:

```
if exist "D:\Data\%%~m" copy "D:\Data\%%~m" subdir
```

You can learn about these substitutions from `for /?`. The variable substitution can contain other operations, for example `%%~nm` and `%%~tm` to exatract the file name or datestamp.